# What's the sequence?

Tags: pattern, logical-deduction

Joe likes 2025 but not 2024; he likes 529 but not 530; he likes 400 but not 500.
Which does Joe like - 3600 or 3700? Why?

Comment: Can you comment on the second answer that I provided or provide more clarity or hints

Comment: To answer your question I would have to submit the answer to the people that requested it from me. Since I never solved it I don't feel appropriate to provide the answer to them. Therefore we will never know which is the correct answer.

Comment: Since the asker has no idea what the answer is I propose closing this as primarily opinion based

Comment: Seconded. Why post a puzzle you don't know the solution for?

Comment: Well I didn't know I had to know the answer to the puzzle. Sorry, I guess I should have learned the forum rules.

Answer (score 9):

> He likes 3600 because that is a perfect square (60*60) like the other numbers.
>
> 2025 = 45*45
>
> 529 = 23*23
>
> 400 = 20*20

Comment: so there's another answer...hummmm

Answer (score 8):

Another response similar to the answer given earlier

> When you add the digits in the numbers he likes it results in perfect squares so he likes 3600
>
>
> 2+0+2+5 =9
>
>
> 5+2+9=16
>
>
> 4+0+0=4

Comment: That's a very interesting answer. Correct tho.